# Список в котором 200к имен городов

Tags: c#, строки, cmd

Пишу веб сервис, получение данных по погоде в городе. Есть список городов в котором 200к имен. Решил выводить по первой букве города. На букву "А" 11к городов. И в командную строку( даже если все в одну строку собрать) не помещается.
Подскажите как можно решить проблему?

Comment: А зачем вам нужна командная строка, для чего вы ее используете ?

Comment: @Mike для вывода на экран

Comment: начинай со второй буквы

Comment: @eri в смысле с двух букв? P.s.с какой бы буквы не начинал, количество слов значительно не уменьшится)

Comment: А смысл вообще выводить в консоль если это веб сервис? Если вам нужно выводить в лог отладочную информацию - используйте файлы

Comment: А какое отношение вывод на консоль имеет к передаче через командную строку названий всех городов ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Варианты:

1. Сделайте сначала выбор страны и региона
2. Если у вас что-то типа combobox, выводите туда только первые 5 городов, а при вводе пользователем следующей буквы, уточняйте запрос и выводите новые 5 городов. Примерно так, как делает адресная строка Chrome при вводе произвольного запроса по отдельным буквам.